# Installing garamondx font

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive

I'm trying to install the garamondx fonts. Following [the installation instructions](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/garamondx/README), all this works fine:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c
sudo /bin/cp -Rfp * /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
sudo echo Map zgm.map >> /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg
sudo mktexlsr
```

until I get to the step:

```
sudo -H updmap-sys
```

which leads to:

```
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
pxdvi output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pxdvi/updmap"

ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
        zgm.map (in /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg)

        Did you run mktexlsr?

        You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
          --syncwithtrees.
```

I *did* run mktexlsr, and it gave:

```
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
```

The map file

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

contains:

```
Map zgm.map
```

What (am I doing/is going) wrong? As you can see from the above, I use Texlive 2013 (on OS X).

PS. I found someone else with the [same problem on fr.comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fr.comp.text.tex/DM0dB7HnnYs/vNoP61LDBVQJ), but my French is not good enough for technical problems anymore…

**UPDATE:** Here's the output in response to Ulrike Fischer's second comment:

```
[…]

{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file zgm.map): cannot open font map file
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
)) (./garamondx.sty
Package: garamondx 2013/09/30 GaramondNo8 with expert features (Michael Sharpe)

[…]

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/t1zgmx.fd
File: t1zgmx.fd 2012/10/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/zgmx.
)
! Font T1/zgmx/m/n/10=T1-zgm-r-lf at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
 found.
<to be read again>
                   relax
l.118 \normalfont

? x
```

Comment: Does the file `zgm.map` itself exist somewhere? updmap.cfg is not a map file, it is a configuration file and it is not enough to write the word "zgm.map" in it.

Comment: It exists in the installation directory in the subdirectory `map`. You say that it is not enough to write the word "zgm.map" in it, but isn't that what the installation instructions effectively ask the user to do?

Comment: Well updmap-sys is looking for the map-file. So it must be somewhere updmap can find it. If you add to a simple latex file \pdfmapfile{=zgm.map} does the log-file show that it has been loaded successfully?

Comment: I'm going to put the output into an update of my question to better show the content.

Comment: So obviously zgm.map can't be found.  Where is it exactly?

Comment: I should have made it more clear before that because the installation is not complete, I don't see any reason why the file should be found. At the moment, it's only in the installation directory, nowhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following a suggestion by Michael Sharpe, the maintainer of garamondx, I used the [getnonfreefonts](http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) script, which resolved the problem.